# Just starting to use Java which IDE is better for me to start out?

Tags: java, ide

I am learning Java now (yay) in my spare time and have started several different tutorials.  Some tutorials say to use NetBeans, some say to use Eclipse.  Eventually I would like to get into Android development because i will be getting a smart phone at the end of this year.

FYI:  I just earned Commentator Badge.

UPDATE::::::::I Have also just earned the "Notable Question" and "Editor" Badges respectively

2nd Update::::Soon after earning the two badges noted in the previous update, i also earned the Scholar Badge.

Comment: No not to be subjective, just wondering which is best for beginners

Comment: More important than what works best for beginners ... is what works best for Billy? And there's only one way to find that out!

Comment: @glowcoder i guess i was more asking if one is harder than another to learn, i started out with Visual Studio, but wanted to gain more knowledge about another IDE for school projects etc

Comment: If you got visual studio under your belt, none of the others are going to be a giant stretch for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your first programming language, then it's just a matter of what you like best. Try NetBeans; if you like it, keep using it forever, or until you start hating it or it doesn't do something you need. If you don't like it, try Eclipse. Rinse, repeat. You could even get away with using a simple text editor and javac in the command line.

It all comes down to what your preferences and needs are at this time. If, for example, you were just starting to learn PHP as a first language, I'd tell you to use Notepad++. Eventually you're going to want support for debugging, version control, PHPDOC, etc. You'll outgrow Notepad++ and graduate to Zend Studio or similar; but for now, you don't need the bells and whistles.

Personally, I've mostly used NetBeans (for Java/PHP), but the editor is a bit finicky sometimes. It's nothing debilitating though, and if I wasn't lazy I could probably fix most of the issues in the options. It was the first IDE wherein I could get the version control plugins (for Git in particular) to work properly so I stuck with it. To be fair, you can do this easily in most IDE's now.

However, I'm trying to convert to using Eclipse exclusively. The Android SDK is built to work hand-in-hand with it and Zend Studio is practically the same program, so it all feels very familiar. This is a good example of what I mean by one's personal needs and preferences.

Comment: I will probably start with netbeans then because homeandlearn.co.uk has an intro java tutorial that suggests it, i was a little apprehensiv though because the tutorial seemed somewhat old

Comment: @Billy NetBeans will treat you right. Like someone else already said, it's pretty good for UI design and it's very intuitive, so you'll probably have an experience similar to mine: sticking with it until the playing field changes substantially.

Answer (score 5):

If you're heading towards Android development, I would suggest using Eclipse, because the Android SDK nicely integrates with Eclipse.

Comment: I use netbeanas for everything Java except android development.

Comment: Sure, and personaly I use Eclipse for everything except PHP, for which I use Netbeans ;-) But if this guy is to learn how to use an IDE, then it's probably not a bad idea to start with one that can meet most of his needs...

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be a very subjective answer, but i like intellij.

The community edition now has support for android development, and I have found that it is usually a good few years ahead of the other ide's as far as features are concerned.

Comment: BTW: IntelliJ has builtin, free Android support, rather than as an extra plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Install one.

Try using it.

Like it? Keep it. Don't like it? Try another.

Repeat.

The list of some to try: (there's plenty more out there!)

```
Eclipse // most popular
NetBeans // most popular for gui development
IntelliJ // holds its own in popularlity
BlueJ // simple
JGrasp // simple, made by a university for university students
```

The thing that make it best for you ... only you know, so only you can answer, and only after trying them yourself!

Answer (score 2):

start with the command prompt. when you attain nirvana, the answer to your question will present itself to you. (in case you don't, try netbeans (good for GUI) or eclipse (for andriod development)).

Comment: @Dhruv There is no call for rudeness that really hurt my feelings.

Comment: @Billy heh, what i meant was for you to use a text editor along with a command prompt as the environment. my baaaad! :) oh c'mon, i didn't mean to offend you. its just my way of welcoming new users! chill out dude, life's too short to be angry all the time...

Comment: @Billy haha, sorry man, its sometimes hard to detect sarcasm when text is being used. still, i stand by my answer. i love nirvana. my personal favourite is netbeans in case you were wondering.

Comment: @Dhruv Kind note to you: Nirvana has not been together for years and its lead singer passed away....

Answer (score 1):

I like [IntellJ IDEA](https://web.archive.org/web/20150519071719/http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/training/demos/CE/introduction_to_community_edition.html)  specially for beginners because you can get started very quickly without having to know deeply the tool.

If you want to use it as a simple text editor, it's easy, if you wan to start using more advanced features, they are discoverable.

The problem I've seen with Eclipse for instance, is sometimes I found it hard to know what to do next. But that's probably because I'm more used to IDEA.

The community edition [has Android support](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/).

[image: android support]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/screenshots/90/android/run.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet when starting out is using a simple text editor and the command prompt to compile/run.

Answer (score 0):

When I started programming in Java we used BlueJ in my class. An IDE will maybe do to much work for you in the start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to do Android in the future, I would definitely recommend Eclipse.  Google has a set of plugins that integrate really nicely into Eclipse.

I also personally prefer Eclipse over NetBeans, but that's just my opinion.  I have also not used other popular IDEs like IntelliJ, so take that with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

1. For learning java start with texteditor like notepad++ or any othere. So you can get familiar with setting path , compiling and running for java program.
2. As  you want to move to Android than best option is after some days move to eclipse.

Comment: How can I compile a java program and run it from notepad++? Do y ou have any resources? thx

Comment: I am not suggesting . Notepad++ for automation . 
starting with text editor is just suggested to understand work flow. 
It is for learning purpose. So use cmd or shell depending on your os. To compile the program.

Answer (score 0):

For beginners I think Netbeans would be better, Eclipse is sometime a bit hard on novice.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a balanced answer here, as I haven't used NetBeans extensively, and not at all for some years, nor have I used IntelliJ (which I hear is very good).

I'm an Eclipse guy. There's a definite learning curve attached, but there is method to the madness and once you learn the basic concepts, they'll take you a long way. It's a powerful tool.

Actually, I use SpringSource Tool Suite nowadays, which is Eclipse with some Spring-oriented extensions built-in. As with everything they do, SpringSource does a nice job of putting together a cohesive distribution, and it's great if you're going to be using Spring. If you're just starting out with Java, though, it's probably not necessary or helpful.

I will second others' comments about starting with a good text editor and javac on the command line, at least for a little while. If you understand what's happening with the compile and run process, it will help you drive any IDE.

But, IDEs are highly worthwhile in Java. It's a verbose language compared to, say, Ruby or Python, but a good IDE will manage that boilerplate for you, and give you great navigation and refactoring tools.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse tends to be used a LOT in big corporate java shops, but Netbeans is used exclusively in Sun/Oracle's training courses. I'd recommend Eclipse because of its ubiquity within the industry - but try & learn to do without IDEs unless you're doing something really complex. When you're learning the basics of Java or when you're gearing up for certification the IDEs can provide too much of a crutch sometimes so you don't learn the syntax properly.

Comment: But how can a program compile without an IDE?

Comment: Sorry for late reply: essentially all you need is the JDK with its /bin directory in your PATH - on Windows this is found by pressing the Windows key plus Pause/Break (top right of your keyboard), selecting the Advanced tab then the Environment Variables button at the bottom of that, then editing the PATH variable. On Unix, Linux & OSX it's set in your .profile or .bashrc files.

Comment: So basically you type out your programs in Notepad, TextMate or whatever you prefer (Life's easier if you have syntax highlighting at least - I recommend Notepad++ or TypePad on Windows, TextMate on OSX), then opening up a command line, going into the directory where you saved your work & typing something like 'javac Myclass.java'. Chances are you'll get a lot of show-stopping syntax errors & classpath issues, but it forces you to think hard about your code as you write, forces you to learn java properly.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is very popular and has a great debugger for java (I've heard better than Netbeans). If you are not going to program swing applications I would recommend Eclipse. For swing applications, Netbeans has a great designer.
I've also heard that IntelliJ is a great IDE but I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides convenient Eclipse plugins for many of their technologies like [Android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), GWT, AppEngine, etc. So for that reason Eclipse would probably be a nice IDE if you are interested in Android development. I personally am happy using Eclipse for Java development and have had no reason so far to try NetBeans. Probably others can better explain the pros and cons of the different IDEs. Here is a [comparison table of Java IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#Java)s that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've found using Eclipse and Netbeans for several years:

Eclipse is bloated and not as well integrated as Netbeans which is probably because it's older.

Eclipse has a better emacs mode and has collected more tools over the years.

Netbeans has the major advantage of being 100% Java, so I can have one shared install that's used across all our platforms and users.   There's no worrying about different configurations on everyone's individual systems.   This is mostly across Unix platforms as Windows is not nearly as flexible.

As people have mentioned Android is using Eclipse as the officially supported development platform, but there are 3rd party plugins that work just as well in Netbeans.

Overall they're similar enough I don't have much of a problem switching back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is trying to have an IDE with an easily accessible Console.

For my university courses (University of Washington) we actually used Dr. Java, and a feature that I ended up using all the time was the easily accessible and ever present console at the bottom of the application.

As a beginner you often find yourself wanting to see if  `"0" == False`  or if you can  `cast`  a value and it works correctly.

I eventually switched to Eclipse when working with bigger programs with multiple classes, but found using the Eclipse console a lot less intuitive.